# React .map with .filter - any performance benefits by immutableJS / shouldcomponent update?

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I have a array with objects in my state, which is fairly bog (e.g. 2000 objects to my quess)...

Currently I work with a mocked dataset which only has 100 objects in the array, and my using the React .map function, I render them to my screen. Using the final state, I will implement some pagination (of course)

I filter on the state by various filter functions which I call during the .filter function, just before the .map function is called.

All works pretty ok, although I do notice quite some delays, especially on mobile devices. If I look ar React.Perf() I also notice quite some time waste during manual filter changes.

Now I was thinking, how to improve the performance (to the max at least).

- I don't think I can use Shouldcomponentupdate within the element I call within my .map function, since they all iterate over the complete set and will therefore always be different compared to their previous one.
- But I was also reading a bit on immutable.js. Does anyone see any performance optimizations using immutable.js (with such a big state) or shouldcomponentupdate?

If you need some code from me, I am willing to share.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[edit] I would also like to add the total counts in the frontend behind every filter, so that you know how many items are within that filter. (the app is for traveltickets, I would like to show e.g. the number of offers behind each destination checkbox (filter) Would this usecase better suit immutable js?[/edit]

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend you to use the `react-addons-update` package, from the immutability helpers from React.

[Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) // this should help you.

it's faster, and you can use it with immutable-js to gain higher performance.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your answer. I dont fully inderstand why to use update, since I am not changing the state with my filters.. See below for my code.